# How to limit dropdown list to options based on an existing relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have three models that are related.
A church model, a campus model and a user model.
A user belongs_to a campus and a user belongs_to a church
A campus has_many users and a campus belongs_to a church
A church has_many users and a church has_many campuses.

All of that seems to be fine... I think.

In order to have an account, a user is assigned a church but having a campus is optional.
So... in the user edit form, I need to provide a dropdown select that only displays campuses that belong to the users church.

I can create the dropdown in simple_form like this in my edit.html.erb file

```
<%= f.association :church %>
```

However that displays all of the campuses available to any church in the system. 
What is the best way to limit the dropdown options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple form allows to use collection option to limit number of items, like this:

```
f.association :campus, collection: Campus.where(church_id: current_user.church_id)
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. I knew it should be easy just couldn't find it anywhere.